# Prevent meatballs menu from hiding explorer menu items

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-11

When a Windows 11 explorer window becomes too small to display all items in the menu/top bar, it hides overflowing items in a meatballs menu.

[image: Not enough space to display all items]

But when there's ample space to show more or even all of them, it still hides some arbitrary amount.

[image: More than enough space to display all items]

Is there anyway to change this behaviour? To let it just show everything that fits?

Comment: That's actually a 'meatballs' menu, kebab is vertical - for a whole smorgasbord of foodstuff-shaped menus, see https://uxplanet.org/choose-correct-menu-icon-for-your-navigation-7ffc22df80ac

Comment: Hamburger, Kebab, Meatballs... was someone hungry?

Comment: Lol @Tetsujin I actually looked it up, saw it was meatballs, and then typed kebab.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hiding ***some arbitrary amount***, instead there are the 'more advance' options (after *View*) which will always be hidden.

There is no way to change that, since it's the way this program is designed to show.

(You can perhaps try an alternative File Explorer that replaces the Windows File Explorer and has more options in the ribbon.)

Comment: Ok then, ***some arbitrary selection*** then. Because somebody just decided that e.g. "Options" is... too advanced to show?

Comment: Too advanced or less frequently used. You never used to see all options in the first ten on the ribbon (though you obviously used to see more) you could had the same question/complaints on the things they were under the Share or View tabs if the ribbon